# Spring Hibernate configuration with setting unitName in @PersistenceContext

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have seen a few questions here and online about this but they dont seem to quite match the error message I am getting.

I have been using JPA annotations within my code to deal with the database. I use the @PersistenceContext annotation to configure the entity manager. This all works well until I add more than one persistence unit to my persistence xml. I then want to call

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "myPU")
```

I was then getting problems saying that no bean with name myPU was found

I have actaully removed the second persistence unit from my persistence.xml and am just trying to basically reference my one persistence unit by name (I know this is not needed but will be once I add another pu).

My persistence.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="myPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/mycore</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

and my core-context.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd  
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd">

<context:annotation-config/>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.mine.model"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor">
    <property name="persistenceUnits">
        <map>
            <entry key="myPU" value="jdbc/mycore"/>

        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<tx:jta-transaction-manager/>
<tx:annotation-driven/>

<jee:jndi-lookup id="entityManagerFactory" jndi-name="jdbc/mycore"/>
```

The exact error I get is

```
Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app :  java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myfirstbean': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'myPU' is defined. Please see server.log for more details.
```

Currently I am trying to deploy to Glassfish.

Can anyone help? Im sure I am missing something quite basic here

Thanks

**EDIT**

I tried the answer MasterSlave gave and this unfortunately did not work.

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "myPU", name="jdbc/mycore")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get this going by cleaning out my core-context.xml file and removing several lines that were not needed. I found [this](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?115587-Example-for-using-two-databases-w-Spring-amp-JTA-transaction-manager) particularly useful

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" ... and some more stuff>

   <context:annotation-config/>
   <context:component-scan base-package="com.my.model"/>

   <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>
   <tx:jta-transaction-manager/>
   <tx:annotation-driven/>

   <jee:jndi-lookup id="corePU" jndi-name="jdbc/mycore"/>
</beans>
```